# Not validating one of the search fields

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to check if either of my search fields are empty, and if they are i write out a failure message. For some reason the following code doesn't work when I try to submit empty values in both search fields, or leaving the q2 search field empty. It only writes out the failure message when I only insert a value into the first field. Hope you guys can help.

```
<div id="searchField">
    <form name="searchField" action="" method="get">
        <input type="search" name="q" id="submitQuery" autofocus="autofocus" value="<?= $_GET['q']; ?>" placeholder="enter one movie"/> 
        <input type="search" name="q2" id="submitQuery2" value="<?= $_GET['q2']; ?>" placeholder="and then another one"/> 
        <input type="hidden" id="v" name="v" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" id="b" name="b" value="" />
        <button type="submit" id="loop" style="border:0px; background:transparent; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:-85px; margin-top:-3px;">
            <img src="images/loop.png" width="75" height="75" alt="submit" />       
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="theData">

<?
if(str_replace(" ", "",$_GET['q'])!="" && str_replace(" ","",$_GET['q2'])!=""){
    $qContent = $_GET['q'];
    $succes = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM film WHERE name='".$qContent."'");
    include("searchMaster.php");
    if(mysql_num_rows($succes)) {
        while($o = mysql_fetch_array($succes)){
            echo $o['name'];
            if($o['trailer']){
                echo '<div id="ytplayerWrap">';
                echo '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$o['trailer'].'?http://amnestic.ueuo.com"
                frameborder="0"/>';
                echo '</div>';
            }else {
                echo '<span style="font-size:20px;">';
                echo '<br /><br /> No trailer was found for <em>'.$_GET['q'].'</em> :(';
                echo '</span>';
            }
        }
    }else{
     echo 'You did the fuckup :(';
    }
}else{
echo 'You did the fuckup :(';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name and id of your input fields must be same
Like this

```
<input type="text" name="submitQuery" id="submitQuery" autofocus="autofocus" value="<?= $_GET['q']; ?>" placeholder="enter one movie"/> 
<input type="text" name="submitQuery2" id="submitQuery2" value="<?= $_GET['q2']; ?>" placeholder="and then another one"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem :( Do you have any other idea?

Comment: The id's of the input fields has absolutely nothing to do with validating this form on the server side.

Comment: Sorry try changing the input type=search to input type=text in the input fields.

Comment: I also thought of this, which didn't do anything either.